# Solving a Set of Linear Equations Not Working Correctly

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following homogeneous equation:

$$
S.B=\tilde{B}.S
$$

Where

$$
\tilde{B}
$$
is a diagonal matrix.

Here is the code:

$$
S=\text{LinearSolve}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 c_1 & -c_2 & 0 \\
 0 & c_3 & -c_1 \\
 0 & 0 & c_2 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & -\lambda _1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2 & -\lambda _2 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda _3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda _3 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 c_1 & -c_2 & 0 \\
 0 & c_3 & -c_1 \\
 0 & 0 & c_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]
$$

Where

$$
S = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 c_1 & -c_2 & 0 \\
 0 & c_3 & -c_1 \\
 0 & 0 & c_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & -\lambda _1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2 & -\lambda _2 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda _3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\tilde{B} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda _3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The quantity
$$
S.B.S^{-1}
$$
should be equal to the diagonal matrix $\tilde{B}$

Any help would be great - Thanks!

Here is the raw code:

```
 S = LinearSolve[( {
 {Subscript[c, 1], -Subscript[c, 2], 0},
 {0, Subscript[c, 3], -Subscript[c, 1]},
 {0, 0, Subscript[c, 2]}
} ).( {
 {Subscript[λ, 1], -Subscript[λ, 1], 0},
 {0, Subscript[λ, 2], -Subscript[λ, 2]},
 {0, 0, Subscript[λ, 3]}
} ), ( {
 {Subscript[λ, 1], 0, 0},
 {0, Subscript[λ, 2], 0},
 {0, 0, Subscript[λ, 3]}
} ).( {
 {Subscript[c, 1], -Subscript[c, 2], 0},
 {0, Subscript[c, 3], -Subscript[c, 1]},
 {0, 0, Subscript[c, 2]}
} )]
```

Comment: From the docs: "`LinearSolve[m,b]` finds an `x` that solves the matrix equation `m.x==b`."

Comment: How do you copy-past in MMA via Mathematica?

Comment: The code looks "funky" when I paste it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attempts to solve a matrix equation `S.B.x==Bdiag.S` - read the docs of `LinearSolve`.

The matrix equation you want to solve is

```
S = {{c1, -c2, 0}, {0, c3, -c1}, {0, 0, c2}};
B = {{L1, -L2, 0}, {0, L2, -L2}, {0, 0, L3}};
Bdiag = DiagonalMatrix[{L1, L2, L3}];

Solve[S.B == Bdiag.S, {c1, c2, c3}]
```

> {{c1 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 0}}

which gives only a trivial solution. I guess what you really want to do is find the eigenvectors:

```
Eigenvalues[B]
```

> {L1, L2, L3}

```
s = Transpose @ Eigenvectors[B]
```

> {{1, L2/(L1 - L2), -(L2^2/((L2 - L3) (-L1 + L3)))}, {0, 1, L2/(
>     L2 - L3)}, {0, 0, 1}}

```
Inverse[s].B.s // FullSimplify
```

> {{L1, 0, 0}, {0, L2, 0}, {0, 0, L3}}

The last line shows that the equation is indeed satisfied with the solution.

Comment: This looks correct - Thank you! I have one more question - It seems when I use subscripts I get a different answer (an incorrect one). Is that right or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PierreMFiorini Subscripts rarely behave like expected. They should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1):

For advice on (not) using subscripts, please take a look at these [basic syntax issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395).

As to your system of equations, there may be solutions for particular values of the $\lambda's$.  Let's take another look at the equation(s) you want to solve, not using subscripts (or capital letters for variable names).  First, consider these commands

```
s = {{c1, -c2, 0}, {0, c3, -c1}, {0, 0, c2}};
b = {{λ1, -λ1, 0}, {0, λ2, -λ2}, 
    {0, 0, λ3}};
c = DiagonalMatrix[{λ1, λ2, λ3}];

eqn = Thread[s.b == c.s];
eqn // ColumnForm
```

which give us the following rows of the matrix `eqn`

$\begin{array}{l}
 \{\text{c1} \text{$\lambda $1},-\text{c1} \text{$\lambda $1}-\text{c2} \text{$\lambda $2},\text{c2} \text{$\lambda $2}\}=\{\text{c1} \text{$\lambda $1},-\text{c2} \text{$\lambda $1},0\} \\
 \{0,\text{c3} \text{$\lambda $2},-\text{c3} \text{$\lambda $2}-\text{c1} \text{$\lambda $3}\}=\{0,\text{c3} \text{$\lambda $2},-\text{c1} \text{$\lambda $2}\} \\
 \text{True} \\
\end{array}$

The last row is an identity for all values of our variables.  Let's apply `Thread` again, like this

```
eqs = Union@Flatten[Thread /@ eqn];
eqs // ColumnForm
```

Now we have the following equations in the list `eqs`

$\begin{array}{l}
 \text{True} \\
 c2 \lambda2 = 0 \\
 -c1 \lambda1-c2 \lambda2 =-c2\lambda1 \\
 -c3 \lambda2-c1 \lambda3=-c1\lambda2 \\
\end{array}$

So now we can almost find solutions by hand.  However, let's use the `Reduce` command like this

```
Reduce[eqs] // ColumnForm
```

Now we have the following list of possible solutions:

$\begin{array}{c}
 \text{$\lambda $3}=0\land \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1}=0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{c2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1}\neq 0\land \text{c1}=0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1}=0\land \text{c1}=0\land \text{$\lambda $3}\neq 0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1} \text{$\lambda $3}\neq 0\land \text{c2}=0\land \text{c1}=0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $3}=0\land \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1}=0\land \text{c2}=0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $3}=0\land \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1}\neq 0\land \text{c1}=\text{c2} \\
 \text{$\lambda $1} \text{$\lambda $2}\neq 0\land \text{c3}=0\land \text{c2}=0\land \text{c1}=0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $1}=0\land \text{c2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $2}-\text{$\lambda $3}\neq 0\land \text{c1}=\frac{\text{c3} \text{$\lambda $2}}{\text{$\lambda $2}-\text{$\lambda $3}}\land \text{$\lambda $2}\neq 0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $1}=0\land \text{c2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $3}\neq 0\land \text{c1}=0 \\
 \text{$\lambda $2}=\text{$\lambda $3}\land \text{$\lambda $1}=0\land \text{c3}=0\land \text{c2}=0\land \text{$\lambda $3}\neq 0 \\
\end{array}$

The tent-like $\land$ in the above should be a double-and, like `&&`.  Some of the above solutions may tell us something about our system equations, like what conditions are required for a solution to exit.